# How to fix a small pond that has become stagnant?

Tags: water, pond

I'm working in a park and we have a small pond, a part of a river system that has become stagnant, mucky and smelly. The river that previously ran into the pond is no longer there and we'd like to be able to make the pond less mucky and have clear water. The pond has a small stream that flows out of it, but the pond itself doesn't seem to have any water flow whatsoever. The bottom is all mud and has no wildlife, expect for a few leaves.The pond is about 2 feet deep, 7 feet across and about 12 feet long. So its relatively small. It's located in Paradise, Newfoundland, Canada. The pond is in a park surrounded by mostly pine trees. And a lot of moss. I'm assuming a river once ran into the pond but now it's mostly boggy moss.
Our project for the summer is to try to get the pond to flow again or just make it so it doesn't smell and has clearer water. What can we do? (We have no money to work with, just manual labour.)

Comment: Can you provide more info about the size of the pond and water level? Also, provide some info about the geology of your region. But I like your question :)

Comment: The pond is about 2 feet deep, 7 feet across and about 12 feet long. So its relatively small. It's located in Paradise, Newfoundland, Canada. The pond is in a park surrounded by mostly pine trees. And a lot of moss. I'm assuming a river once ran into the pond but now it's mostly boggy moss. I hope that helps, if you need more information let me know!

Comment: Really interesting question but I agree that Gardening and Landscaping SE will probably provide you with more useful answers!

Comment: I thought about it but I am still not sure if gardening SE deals with these topics. This may not even be about plants. At this moment searching "Eutrophication" does not return any posts on G&L. This perhaps needs more expertise on ecology. @GreenTeamParadise You can add the info in your comment to the question.

Comment: You need to explain the setting more clearly. You write that "a river" used to flow in to the pond, when the pond is only 7 by 12 feet. You also write that a stream is running out of it, whisky should drain a 7x12 feet pond quickly if it doesn't have an inflow. Your explanation doesn't make sense to me. It would also be useful to know about the soil type and how the pond lies in the surroundings ( elevation etc).

Comment: @fileunderwater you would assume that the pond would drain with how it has no flow into it, but flow out. But it doesn't. I'm assuming there's some underwater flow going into the pond. I'm not sure why it isn't draining, but it isn't. The soil is acidic and rocky. And the pond is pretty level with the ground. I have a picture of it, i'm not sure if there's a way I can add a picture or not

Comment: Is there gravel/rock under the mud, or is it dirt all the way down? Find out with a pole and a hammer. Unless there's a regular watershed, that outflow suggests there's a spring down there somewhere. Unplugging it by removing muck and branches could help a lot. Of course, first you've got to find the thing. At 2 feet deep, that shouldn't be too hard; there's got to be *some* current down there.

Answer (score 3):

You should at least spring for a water test. My guess is that the water is [hypoxic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypoxia_(medical)), perhaps due to [eutrophication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eutrophication) from fertilizer runoff. If so, then a bubbler system could help (perhaps donated for credit), along with trying to limit the fertilizer runoff.

Comment: To my knowledge, there's no fertiliser used in the park. But I'll check into the bubbler system! Thanks for your help

Comment: @GreenTeamParadise you will get nutrient drainage from the surrounding flower beds/plantings even if they aren't fertilized per se, especially if they are replanted or topdressed each year.